# How to get current authenticated user/group from apache2 with php

Tags: php, apache

I have a security.conf file that requires users to login whenever they visit my site.
Now I want the php pages to only show certain links to the users that are in the admins group in my .htgroup file. So the question is how do I get the group(s) that a user, that was authenticated by apache, is in, for use in my php scripts.

my .htgroup file looks like this
admins: user1 user2
users: user1 user2 user3 user4 user 5....

so it IS possible that a user is part of multiple groups because for certain parts of the site I only require that the person is a user. Other parts of the site I require that he/she is an admin, and for some parts I require a specific user.

If you have any ideas I would really appreciate it.

Thanks, Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$_SERVER['REMOTE_USER']` will contain the Apache-authenticated username.

You can parse the `.htgroup` file to determine to which groups that corresponds, or connect to (and query) the original source of the group information. So far as I know, it's not handed from Apache to PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Or u can try this

```
  if (isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']) && isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'])) {
     $authFile = file("./password.txt");

     foreach ($authFile as $login) {
         list($username, $password) = explode(":", $login);
         $password = trim($password);
         if (($username == $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']) && ($password == md5($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']))) {
            $authorized = TRUE;
            break;
         }
      }
   }

   // If not authorized, display authentication prompt or 401 error
   if (! $authorized) {
      header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic Realm="Secret Stash"');
      header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
      print('You must provide the proper credentials!');
      exit;
   }
```

Comment: <!-- password.txt format:  
username:60d99e58d66a5e0f4f89ec3ddd1d9a80